Would this question about motherboard compatibility with PSUs be acceptable?
It's been a while since I touch CPU spare parts, so I was surprised when I found out that my HP Pro Tower 280 G9 PCI Desktop PC Bundle (6N0F5PA) motherboard is not compatible with my power supply - the "usual version" that works with Gigabyte H610M - which does not work with Gigabyte H61.
I want to ask to "how many versions of motherboards are there, based on the compatibilities with various power supplies?"
Currently, in my head I have three: one that works with H61, with H610M, and this weird motherboard that comes with the HP tower - which I assume is more modern. However, I'm also interested if there's any power supply that can be downgraded - for example, the "2nd-gen" PSU can be used for H61 mainboard - just don't plug theses cables, or something.
I assume this might get old, but not quickly, and can be updated, so can this question be asked here?

HP is notorious for using parts that cannot be upgraded using standard parts.

Dell have also been known to use non-standard PSU pinouts.

The problem with this question is that you're essentially asking us to check or know system reference documentation for you.
This information is either published, hopefully by HP, and thus knowable through any bare amount of research, or is it not published, and thus the only people who would know it with authority would be employees of HP or their partners. Everyone else would be simply guessing.
While it is theoretically possible one of the handful of people in the world who have authoritative knowledge of this may frequent this site, it is unlikely, and that is assuming someone DOES actually know this information, which is not a given.

I'm not asking for HP specifically - if someone does include that information (that HP component is usually different from common components sold in stores), that will be great. Perhaps closer to what I want to ask is the "generation" of motherboard-PSU compatibility? During my research, I found out about ATX and such. Would that be a good idea to ask those instead? I don't know what category is that, so I use "compatibility"

You may not know that you're asking about HP specifically, but Criggie's good response should illustrate that you are, in fact, asking specifically about HP.

Everything uses the industry-standard ATX motherboard connector with 20 or 24 pins.
...except for those that don't, like HP and Dell and IBM.   Notice how its always a "brand name" that pulls shenanigans with proprietary parts?  That's because they have the customer-base large enough to make it viable.
So this question, if posted, would turn into an ever-growing list of anecdotes about "how X motherboard failed with Y PSU"
Dell was extra-nasty by using a standard physical connector, but swapping a 12V and Ground pin from the spec.  This resulted in a dead Dell motherboard if a user swapped in a non-dell PSU, and likewise if someone moved a Dell PSU to a generic PC, it would also kill the board.  This was in the era of the Pentium3, so you're not likely to see it outside of retro gear nowdays.
The average white-box brand doesn't have the ability to maintain a supply chain of their own unique specific parts, so complying with both published and de-facto standards is less of a burden.
Call it a cop-out answer, but we have standards so questions of compatibility and interchangeability are reasonably-reduced.
Computers/IT isn't the only place this game is played - car parts, bicycle components, camera accessories all have mutually-incompatible interfaces and protocols, purely to exclude "non-original parts"

I appreciate the concern with the worry about anecdotes answers, but those informations are actually valuable, IMO. If it's just a rant, the voting system can handle it (or flagging it).

@Vylix —The information shared doesn't answer the question you asked, though. As we are not a discussion forum, it wouldn't be well received as an answer to the question you would have asked on SU.

@Ramhound are you referring to the hypothetical answer that might be posted, or an answer with information such as this answer in this question?
